# What are some questions that you can ask your prospective Ph.D. supervisor during interview?

Tags: graduate-admissions, united-states, career-path, professorship, interview

I have an interview with a professor for a Ph.D. position in the US next week. As I was going through the possible questions that a professor can ask, so I was wondering what if they ask me if I have any questions regarding working in that specific lab? I mean yes I can ask some basic questions (which may be irrelevant too).
As there are so many people from academia, what you usually expect a candidate to ask? What can be a reasonable and valid question?

Answer (score 0):

That part of the interview is not a test. You simply ask the questions that *you* want to know the answers to, not that somebody on this site told you to ask.